# Send data from javascript to code behind at first load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am actually buidling a web application and I need to get data of the local environment of the machine viewing the application.To do this, I use a little javascript script such as:

```
<script language="javascript">
function GetUserName()
{
    //Permits to get username of client machine
    var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var arpege = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");
    document.getElementById("arpege").value=arpege;
}
</script>
<input type=hidden id="arpege" runat=server />
```

My problem is that this script is executed after the page is loaded and so I can't use it on the page load...

My code on the page load is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection.ConnectionString = ActionSource.ConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();
    String account = arpege.value;
    ...
}
```

But i just get "" in account...

Thanks for your help,

Quentin

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried getting the local user via the Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"] property on the server?

Comment: Nope i never used request.ServerVariables ....

Comment: @Zachary, that's what `User.Identity.Name` is for.

Comment: u want to get value from javascript before page load event in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load occurs on the server side *before* any data is being sent to the client.

you can't do that without initiating a new postback once the page is loaded.

Solution coming up...

EDIT:

So, it (might) be possible to achieve this using some [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
     var arpege = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");
     __doPostBack('__Page', arpege);
});
```

And catch it on the server side:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string arpege= Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; 
}
```

Worth's a shot!

Comment: Won't this cause an infinite postback loop?

Comment: @Rawling, yep, good point, but i'm sure he can come up with a solution for this so it will execute only once (read a value of a `HiddenField` from the client side and act according to it)

Comment: Yes, I have an infinite postback loop so the script is well executed but the value of arpege is null.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the proposition made by Shai could be the following:
generate an asyncpostback on a hidden button.

Like that, the logic could be separated from the Page_Load, and
put instead in the handler attached to the input which generated the asyncpostback.

I don't like to put too much logic in the page_load event, i find it confusing.
the implementation will be a little more complicated though

Answer (score 0):

Get the username server side in Page_Load instead of with an ActiveX control.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection.ConnectionString = ActionSource.ConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    String account = User.Identity.Name;
    // ...

}
```

Also, ActiveX only works in Internet Explorer - `User.Identity.Name` works on the server and therefor all browsers.

Comment: I can't get the username in the page load with "environment.username" because when i deployed it on my server i get the name of the server whereas i want the name of the client machine.

Comment: If i use User.Identity.Name I can get the name of the client machine?

Comment: Yes, `Environment.UserName` is the application identity. However, `User.Identity.Name` is the logged in username.

Comment: To get the client's host name, use [`Request.UserHostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname.aspx).

Comment: Do i need a particular assembly for "User.Identity.Name" ? Because it's not recognized by compiler.Anymore,Request.UserHostName doesn't work in local and i get null.Is this will work once on the server?

Comment: [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) is a property on `Page`, so you should be able to use it in `Page_Load`.

Comment: I found it, it's just Page.User.Identity.Name and ... it works! Tkank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

The ASPX code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnUser" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnRun" runat="server" value="true" />
<asp:Label ID="lblSayHello" runat="server" Text="I dont know you"></asp:Label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var run = $('#hdnRun').val();

        if (run == 'true') {
            var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            $('#hdnUser').val(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
            $('#form1').submit();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

The Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnUser.Value))
        {
            hdnRun.Value = "false";

            lblSayHello.Text = String.Format(@"Hello, {0}", hdnUser.Value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best (easiest) way that I know of sending data from the client to the server is to

**1.** Store it in an asp hidden field

**2.** Click an ASP button via javascript

**3.** Handle the data in the OnClick Event

For example:

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myHf" class="myHf" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="myButton" class="myButton" runat="server" OnClick="myButton_Click" style="display: none;" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function SendMyData(data) {
     document.getElementByClassName('myHf').value = data;
     document.getElementByClassName('myButton').click();
     //I use classes since those won't change - IDs become really long and messed up 
     //in the actual page, and may change depending on where the element is placed.
}
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do whatever you want with myHf.Value

    MyServerMethod(myHf.Value);
}
```

I think that doing it this way is better than using the Page_Load and submitting the form, just because if you are doing enough of these, the Page_Load method can get huge.  But that's just my opinion.